# Cannot exract image from bag file

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I 'm using ROS and I'm trying to follow the tutorials on how to export image and video data from a bag file.I keep having this error
When I execute roslaunch export.launch I got this error

```
> [FATAL] [1394490530.406789364]: Error opening file: play
[rosbag-1] process has died [pid 14368, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosbag/play play -d 2 /home/khmarehman/test.bag __name:=rosbag __log:=/home/khmarehman/.ros/log/7b66fb3a-a896-11e3-b8eb-f4b7e2c88a9b/rosbag-1.log].
log file: /home/khmarehman/.ros/log/7b66fb3a-a896-11e3-b8eb-f4b7e2c88a9b/rosbag-1*.log
```

My code

```
<launch> 
   <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="play -d 2 /home/khmarehman/test.bag"/> 
   <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="node"> 
      <remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw"/> 
   </node>
</launch>
```

UPDATE:
I change my code to this

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="-d 2 /home/khmarehman/test.bag"/>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Now it got stuck at

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[rosbag-1]: started with pid [15230]
process[extract-2]: started with pid [15242]
[ INFO] [1394492914.265667303]: Initialized sec per frame to 0.100000
```

UPDATE:
I change the code

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="play -d 2 /home/khmarehman/test.bag">
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="node">
  <remap from="image" to="/front/camera/image_rect_color/compressed"> </remap>
  </node>
  </node>
</launch>
```

still having this error

```
WARNING: WARN: unrecognized 'node' tag in <node> tag. Node xml is <node args="play -d 2 /home/khmarehman/test.bag" name="rosbag" pkg="rosbag" type="play"> <node cwd="node" name="extract" output="screen" pkg="image_view" respawn="false" type="extract_images"> <remap from="image" to="/front/camera/image_rect_color/compressed"> </remap></node></node>

[FATAL] [1394533222.650188690]: Error opening file: play
[rosbag-1] process has died [pid 20032, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosbag/play play -d 2 /home/khmarehman/test.bag __name:=rosbag __log:=/home/khmarehman/.ros/log/2b6a1e2e-a903-11e3-aca7-f4b7e2c88a9b/rosbag-1.log].
log file: /home/khmarehman/.ros/log/2b6a1e2e-a903-11e3-aca7-f4b7e2c88a9b/rosbag-1*.log
```

BAG info

```
path:        test.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    2:10s (130s)
start:       Feb 03 2014 07:21:42.82 (1391394102.82)
end:         Feb 03 2014 07:23:53.55 (1391394233.55)
size:        47.3 MB
messages:    1056
compression: none [61/61 chunks]
types:       sensor_msgs/CompressedImage [8f7a12909da2c9d3332d540a0977563f]
topics:      /front_camera/camera/image_rect_color/compressed   1056 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CompressedImage
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138351/cannot-exract-image-from-bag-file/) by [Mechatronics](https://answers.ros.org/users/13106/mechatronics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-10**:
Is there anything in the logs that it mentions? Have you tried running the same command by hand?

**Comment by [Mechatronics](https://answers.ros.org/users/13106/mechatronics/) on 2014-03-10**:
Sorry, I couldn't understand, what do you mean by hand?

**Comment by [Mechatronics](https://answers.ros.org/users/13106/mechatronics/) on 2014-03-10**:
My updated code worked, But I couldn't find images, they are not in .ros

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-10**:
Rather than running those commands as part of a launch file, try running each command via rosrun and examining the output.

**Comment by [Mechatronics](https://answers.ros.org/users/13106/mechatronics/) on 2014-03-10**:
I am following this tutorial
http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-10**:
I suspect you're not seeing any images because there aren't any images in your bag file on the topic you've specified. You should be able to see which topics are in your bag file, what their types are, and how many messages were recorded on each topic by running `rosbag info` on your bag file.

**Comment by [Mechatronics](https://answers.ros.org/users/13106/mechatronics/) on 2014-03-11**:
I have edited and posted bag info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at your bag file info, your camera topic is `/front_camera/camera/image_rect_color/compressed` ; you should use this topic to extract images.

The third launch example that you posted doesn't close the first `<node>` tag properly, which is why you're seeing an error there.

Therefore, your launch file should be something like:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="-d 2 /home/khmarehman/test.bag"/>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/front_camera/camera/image_rect_color/compressed"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

And this may or may not work because you've only recorded compressed images in your bag file. You may also need to set the `image_transport` parameter to `compressed` to the extraact_images node.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mechatronics](https://answers.ros.org/users/13106/mechatronics/) on 2014-03-11**:
[ WARN] [1394587065.265630274]: [image_transport] It looks like you are trying to subscribe directly to a transport-specific image topic '/front_camera/camera/image_rect_color/compressed', in which case you will likely get a connection error. Try subscribing to the base topic '/front_camera/camera/image_rect_color' instead with parameter ~image_transport set to 'compressed' (on the command line, _image_transport:=compressed). See http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport for details.

**Comment by [Mechatronics](https://answers.ros.org/users/13106/mechatronics/) on 2014-03-11**:
[ERROR] [1394587065.463501301]: Client [/extract] wants topic /front_camera/camera/image_rect_color/compressed to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CompressedImage/8f7a12909da2c9d3332d540a0977563f]. Dropping connection.

**Comment by [Mechatronics](https://answers.ros.org/users/13106/mechatronics/) on 2014-03-11**:
I am stuck again :(

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-11**:
As noted, it looks like you should set the image_transport parameter to compressed for the extract_images node.